# Are there compounds distance functions to define a compounds space metrics

Tags: bond, atomic-structure

Is there exist something like a distance function for compounds, computing a number for any two given molecules? Such a function would measure dissimilarity at the atomic structure and bonds levels, allowing the definition of a metrics on the compounds space.

Comment: Why, of course there is. You might want to read about QSAR.

Comment: Also called molecular descriptors.

Comment: See ["Why is Tanimoto index an appropriate choice for fingerprint-based similarity calculations?"](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13321-015-0069-3)

Comment: @IvanNeretin the main reason would be to determine potential products in chemical reactions.

Comment: To determine products of chemical reactions, you need to code chemistry (all of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous (too many to count) *distance fucntions* to define a compound's *space metrics*.

One of the most commonly used, and one of the first such, index is called the **Wiener Index**, represented by $W$$^1$. It is a topological index; according to [Wikipedia](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=ccbeb5737c454fdaJmltdHM9MTY4MzY3NjgwMCZpZ3VpZD0xZTExMWJmMC1jODIzLTZjYjEtMGJhNS0wYjQ4Yzk1YzZkZTUmaW5zaWQ9NTIxOQ&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=1e111bf0-c823-6cb1-0ba5-0b48c95c6de5&psq=wiener%20index&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvV2llbmVyX2luZGV4&ntb=1):

> In the fields of chemical graph theory, molecular topology, and
> mathematical chemistry, a topological index, also known as a
> connectivity index, is a type of a molecular descriptor that is
> calculated based on the molecular graph of a chemical compound.
> Topological indices are numerical parameters of a graph which
> characterize its topology and are usually graph invariant. Topological
> indices are used for example in the development of quantitative
> structure-activity relationships (QSARs) in which the biological
> activity or other properties of molecules are correlated with their
> chemical structure.

Weiner index $W$ is$^1$

> the sum over all bonds of the product of the number of vertices on
> each side of the bond ([Wiener, 1947a](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01203a022); [Wiener, 1947b](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/15/10/766/361410/Influence-of-Interatomic-Forces-on-Paraffin); [Wiener, 1947c](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01193a005))
> and called at the beginning path number. Usually, the Wiener index is
> defined and calculated as the sum of all topological distances in the
> $\ce{H}$-*depleted molecular graph* ([Hosoya, 1971](https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/abs/10.1246/bcsj.44.2332)).

$\ce{H}$-*depleted molecular graph* means hydrogen atoms are not considered. It is obtained from the $\ce{H}$-depleted distance matrix $D$:

$$
W = \mathcal{W}(D)= \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{A}\sum_{j=1}^{A}d_{ij}\text{,}
$$

where $\mathcal{W}$ is the Wiener operator and $d_{ij}$ is the topological distance. Essentially, it is the sum of all distances between all pairs of atoms, except hydrogen atoms. It has been correlated with properties of compounds such as heat of vaporization and boiling points, especially, for hydrocarbons.

#### Reference

[Handbook of Molecular Descriptors](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9783527613106) by Prof. Dr. Roberto Todeschini, Dr. Viviana Consonni, WILEY-VCH

Comment: Additionally, is there any sort of edit distance between compounds (i.e.: what has to be changed in one compound to obtain another)?